# File storage site with direct link access

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hyperlink

I'm trying to learn angular JS, and I have stumbled upon **$https**.

I wanted to upload a file named **db.php** which contains:

```
{
"vcRecords":
[
    {"name":"Madison"
    ,"nickName":"Madilove"
    ,"coderType":"Injection / Fortress"}
    ,

    {"name":"Stewart"
    ,"nickName":"Stew"
    ,"coderType":"Burst"}
    ,

    {"name":"Kim"
    ,"nickName":"After Shower"
    ,"coderType":"Fortress"}
    ,

    {"name":"Mit"
    ,"nickName":"Mit (N/A)"
    ,"coderType":"Unknown"}
    ,
]
}
```

But the problem is I need a direct link to it so I can load the data inside.
I have tried cloud storage but they only give links like:
http://textuploader.com/pmtu

Is there any site where I can upload data like these on link formats like this?:
[http://storagesite.com/files/db.php](http://#) (Just an example)

(If there are other alternatives please tell me, I'm still a novice at this stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several sites offer raw URLs:

- [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)
- [Hastebin](http://hastebin.com/)
- [GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com)